# Is there a Limit row function in Laravel Excel import?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I am using maatwebsite/excel package to import a CSV file. I cannot able to limit the imported rows. Like I need the first "n" number of rows from the uploaded file. I saw an interface

```
WithLimit
```

But when I am using that with Limit(). It throws some errors, like some table values which I am trying to insert is null. I think it is using the limit for columns. Are there any workarounds to fix the problem?

My controller

```
 class FinancialTransController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new FinancialTrans, request()->file('myfile'));
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

This is my import class

```
class FinancialTrans implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow

{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {  
        return new FinancialTran([
             'module_id' =>$row['sr'],
             'tran_id'=>$row['sr'],
             'amount'=>$row['sr'],
             'crdr'=>$row['sr'],
             'tran_date'=>$row['date'],
             'acad_year'=>$row['academic_year'],
             'entry_mode'=>$row['sr'],
             'voucher_number'=>$row['voucher_no'],
             'br_id'=>$row['sr'],
        ]);
    }
    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 6;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show how you import the csv?

Comment: maybe you got some migration or data insertion issue that is not related to excel import row limiting.

Comment: @Kim De Guzman, Data insertion works without any problem if i am not setting the Limit.

Comment: in your import class.. how did u use the WithLimit

Answer (score 2):

WithHeadingRow loads all previous rows. use interface WithStartRow instead.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithLimit;

class FinancialTrans implements ToModel, WithLimit, WithStartRow
{
    protected $startRow;

    public function __construct(int $startRow)
    {
        $this->startRow = $startRow;
    }
    ... 
    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return $this->startRow;
    }

    public function limit(): int
    {
        return 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look to the [code](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/aa5d2e4d25c5c8218ea0a15103da95f5f8728953/src/Concerns/WithLimit.php) in `maatwebsite/excel`, you can see it is an interface with has a limit function, this one you has to implement. If you are using an IDE, it will often suggest to implement these methods.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithLimit;

class FinancialTrans implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow, WithLimit
{
    public function limit(): int
    {
        return 100; // only take 100 rows
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did the same and it throws an error :
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'module_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `financial_trans` (`module_id`, `tran_id`, `amount`, `crdr`, `tran_date`, `acad_year`, `entry_mode`, `voucher_number`, `br_id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))

Comment: But that is totally unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Module_id cant be null, either your data is null or the module_id field is not fillable on the model

Comment: But how module_id will not be null, if the whole limited rows are getting inserted, I think this is limiting the column with the "withLimit" interface.

Comment: The error is very specific :) you can insert if (!$row['sr']) {dd('module_id is null to check');}